# the application crashed when i used custom adapter with using json

Tags: java, android, json, spinner

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0  in
>   spinner

```
   public void GetAllData() {
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<CityList>mylist=new ArrayList<CityList>();
                    JSONArray array=response.getJSONArray("data");
                    for(int index=0;index<array.length();index++)
                    {
                        JSONObject object=array.getJSONObject(index);
                        mylist.add(new CityList(object.getInt("id"),object.getString("name")));
                    }
                    CityAdapter cityAdapter=new CityAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.custome_spinner,R.id.humanmed,mylist);
                    ServiceName.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
ArrayList<CityList>mylist=new ArrayList<CityList>();
```

use:

```
ArrayList<City>mylist=new ArrayList<City>();
```

Instead of this:

```
mylist.add(new CityList(object.getInt("id"),object.getString("name")));
```

use:

```
City city = new City();
city.setId(object.getInt("id"));
city.setName = (object.getString("name"));

mylist.add(city);
```

You also have to make a class city as:

```
public class City {

private int id;

private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

And create class CityList as:

```
public class CityList {

private List<City> cities;


public List<City> getCities() {
    return cities;
}

public void setCities(List<City> cities) {
    this.cities = cities;
}
```

}

Comment: Please follow this updated answer this will do your job and if it works then please dont forget to mark this post as answer. Happy coding bro :)

Comment: i already did this class its called citylist its contains name and id

Comment: Check updated answer to know how to make cityList class. Thank you :)

Comment: Please use given code then let me know if there is something wrong buddy.

Comment: and for now forget cityList just create class with name city and follow my code then let me know if there is any issue

Comment: ok now in custom adapter i will change citylist class with  city class

Comment: yes instead of citylist use city wherever it is required

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0                            same error

Comment: can you please show me the log where it redirects on clicking the error ?

Comment: Check one more thing are you getting any data in .... JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("data");

Comment: check if data has values and also JSONArray array is not null

Comment: Apply breakpoint at JSONArray array=response.getJSONArray("data"); then press F8 then check if your JSONArray have values in it . Do let me know

Comment: i tried to get data in listview its already done but when i put it in spinner app crashed

Comment: Buddy show me your custom adapter and xml files also.

Comment: MainActivity.this,R.layout.custome_spinner,R.id.humanmed  here replace MainActivity.this with getContext() and I want to see your xmls and adapter class to check if you are using this R.layout.custome_spinner,R.id.humanmed in appropriate way

Comment: public class CityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    int resource;
    ArrayList<City>mylist;
    int resources;
    public CityAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,int textViewId, @NonNull ArrayList mylist) {
        super(context, resource,textViewId);
        this.context=context;
        this.resource=resource;
        this.mylist=mylist;
        this.resources=textViewId;
    }

Comment: ok sorry its first time to use stackoverflow i will copy code now

Comment: https://up.top4top.net/downloadf-6846c5cc1-rar.html                                       i uploaded all file u need i cant copy it here its first time to use stack if u need to copy code here say to me how to put  in comment and iam soor for ur time

Answer (score 0):

only add this to your custom adapter spinner will work

@Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }